# facebook "share" method to share videos using jssdk

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to post video on facebook wall using share method.My website has login feature, once user log in , they can see the video and they can share it. I added following necessary  meta tags to my page.When I debug my url here,using open graph debugger,as my share page needs login credentials, It always takes my home page content for sharing.

FB.ui(
              {
                method: 'share',
                href: 'My video page url',
              },
              function(response) {
                if (response && !response.error_code) {
                 // alert('Posting completed.');
                } else {
                  //alert('Error while posting.');
                }
              }
            );

```
       });
```

Please advise me how to share my video.

Comment: "following necessary meta tags" - well, where are they?

Comment: What sense would it make to share something that only a limited circle of users has access to in the first place?

Comment: ah, i missed the part with the login. yeah, that´s not going to work, obviously.

Comment: I tried me/videos method  which requires publish_actions permission, to get the publish action permission I have to submit my facebook application for reviewing..  Is there any other way to post video on facebook??